# Doxygen output not having search box

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

My doxygen file is having search enabled .  Doxygen  1.9.7

The resultant output is not having search box even though i have this in doxywizard
[image]

My Doxygywizard looks like
[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen / doxygenwizard?

Comment: 1.9.7 . updated question as well

Comment: I do get the search bar. What do you get in the "run tab" when you set the check box "condesed" and click "show configuration"?  What do you on the left hand side of the "run tab" in respect to "Run doxygen" and "Show HTML output" and they gray or grayed out

Comment: I think I see your problem it is `GENERATE_HTMLHELP` as hen just setting the `GENERATE_TMLHELP=YES` I get the warning: "error: When enabling GENERATE_HTMLHELP the SEARCHENGINE option should be disabled. I'll adjust it for you." and this explains why you don't see the the search box.

Comment: Thanks GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO  made it available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @albert making the following change brought back the search bar in Doxygen 1.9.7

```
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
```